# Use/get default image from server if no file is uploaded

Tags: php, image, file-upload

Hi i have a form which ask the user to upload photo. is uses the photo as second image(image on top of another) in imagecreatefromjpg and imagecopyresampled. but it seems like the uploaded image is not being get properly. also the default image is not passed from the server when no file is uploaded. im getting these errors:

```
Warning</b>:  imagecreatefromjpeg() [<a href='function.imagecreatefromjpeg'>function.imagecreatefromjpeg</a>]: Filename cannot be empty in <b>/home/content/52/12096052/html/Testupdate/processor.php</b> on line <b>117</b>

Warning</b>:  imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/content/52/12096052/html/Testupdate/processor.php</b> on line <b>145</b><br />
Warning</b>:  imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/content/52/12096052/html/Testupdate/processor.php</b> on line <b>145</b><br />

<b>Warning</b>:  imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/content/52/12096052/html/Testupdate/processor.php</b> on line <b>145</b><br />

<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/52/12096052/html/Testupdate/processor.php:117) in <b>/home/content/52/12096052/html/Testupdate/processor.php</b> on line <b>186</b><br />
```

this is my code processor.php:

```
    $con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to 
    connect to database! Please try again later.");

    mysql_select_db($dbname);

    // make a note of the current working directory, relative to root.
    $directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

    // make a note of the directory that will recieve the uploaded files //i made it as the same directory where the .php file is
    $uploadsDirectory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory_self;

    // make a note of the location of the upload form in case we need it
    $uploadForm = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'index.php';

    // name of the fieldname used for the file in the HTML form
    $fieldname = 'file';

    // check the upload form was actually submitted else print form
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {           
        if($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']!="")
        {
            $allowedExts = array("jpeg", "jpg");
            $temp = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);
            $extension = end($temp);

            $notallowedExts = array("png", "gif", "pdf", "doc", "docx", "txt", "html", "xlsx", "mov");
            $nottemp = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);
            $notextension = end($nottemp);

            if ((($_FILES['file']['type'] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES['file']['type'] == "image/jpg")) && ($_FILES['file']['size'] < 1300000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))  
            {       

              $now = time();
              while(file_exists($uploadFilename = $uploadsDirectory.$now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]['name']))
              {
                  $now++;
              }
              move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'], $uploadFilename);
            }
            elseif(($_FILES['file']['size'] > 1300000)||(in_array($notextension, $notallowedExts)))
            {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
                echo 'alert("Invalid file upload. Please check your input.");'; 
                echo 'window.location.href = "index.php";';
                echo '</script>';
                die();
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            $uploadFilename = "def_img.jpg";
        }   
    }

    //for textbox input
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $office_id = $_POST['office_id'];
    $var_title = $_POST['title'];
    $var_story = $_POST['story'];
    $var_task = $_POST['task'];
    $var_power = $_POST['power'];
    $var_solve = $_POST['solve'];
    $var_result = $_POST['result'];

    $get_title = $_POST['title'];
    $title = strtoupper ($get_title);
    $namehere = "Super Story By " .$_POST['name'];
    $story = "My super story begins with " . $_POST['story'] . " My task was " . $_POST['task'] ." With the super power of ". $_POST['power'] ." I solved it by ". $_POST['solve'] ." The result was ". $_POST['result'];

    if (!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($office_id) && !empty($title) && !empty($var_title) && !empty($var_story) && !empty($var_task) && !empty($var_power) && !empty($var_solve) && !empty($var_result)) {

    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

    $imagename = $uploadFilename;
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg("bg.jpg");
    $img2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagename);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    $font = 'arialbi.ttf';
    $font2 = 'ariali.ttf';

    $newtitle = wordwrap($title, 24, "\n", true);
    $newertitle = explode("\n", $newtitle);

    imagettftext($im, 33, 0, 8, 270, $black, $font, $newertitle[0]);
    imagettftext($im, 33, 0, 8, 320, $black, $font, $newertitle[1]);
    imagettftext($im, 12, 0, 283, 365, $black, $font, $namehere);

    $newtext = wordwrap($story, 50, "\n", true);
    $newertext = explode("\n", $newtext);
    imagettftext($im, 10, 0, 283, 385, $black, $font2, $newertext[0]);
    imagettftext($im, 10, 0, 283, 400, $black, $font2, $newertext[1]);
    imagettftext($im, 10, 0, 283, 415, $black, $font2, $newertext[2]);
    imagettftext($im, 10, 0, 283, 430, $black, $font2, $newertext[3]);
    imagettftext($im, 10, 0, 283, 445, $black, $font2, $newertext[4]);
    imagettftext($im, 10, 0, 283, 460, $black, $font2, $newertext[5]);
    imagettftext($im, 10, 0, 283, 475, $black, $font2, $newertext[6]);
    imagettftext($im, 10, 0, 283, 490, $black, $font2, $newertext[7]);
    imagettftext($im, 10, 0, 283, 505, $black, $font2, $newertext[8]);
    imagettftext($im, 10, 0, 283, 520, $black, $font2, $newertext[9]);
    imagettftext($im, 10, 0, 283, 535, $black, $font2, $newertext[10]);
    imagecopyresampled($im, $img2, 10, 350, 0, 0, 263, 175, imagesx($img2), imagesy($img2));

    $date_created = date("YmdHis");//get date created
    $img_name = "-img_entry.jpg"; //the file name of the generated image
    $img_newname = $date_created . $img_name; //datecreated+name
    $img_dir =dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) ."/". $img_newname; //the location to save the image 
    imagejpeg($im, $img_dir , 80); //function to save the image with the name and quality

    $newpath = "/home/content/52/12096052/html/Testupdate/image_entry/";
    $newdir = $newpath.$img_newname;
    copy ($img_dir, $newdir); 
    $http_dir = 'https://www.uaewebdeveloper.com/Testupdate/image_entry/';
    $post_link = $http_dir . $img_newname;

    $msg = 'Super Story by ';
    $post_msg = $msg.$name;

    imagedestroy($im);
    }

    else{
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
        echo 'window.alert("*All fields required.");'; 
        echo 'window.location.href = "index.php";';
        echo '</script>';

    }
    //get time to save in db
    $sql_date = date("Y/m/d H:i:s");

    //save inputs to db
    if (!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($office_id) && !empty($title) && !empty($story)) {

        $save_sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tbl_amatest` (filename, name, email, office_id, title, story, time) VALUES ('$img_newname','$name','$email','$office_id','$title','$story','$sql_date')");

        header('Location:' .'success.html'); 
        mysql_close($con);
    }
```

when i specify the second image as the dafault, it works. but it's getting the only the default not the uploaded when someone uploads a file. so basically, i have two problems here:

1. the uploaded image is not being passed/uploaded properly
2. the default image is not being get from the server properly

please help me. i dont know what to do. i have read posts, almost the same but it didn't help me. thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Check directory permissions & use isset function.

Comment: @Rohit what do you mean by check directory permission? im using godaddy here as server. can you give me sample code? honestly, i need a code to guide me. thanks

Comment: Directory in which you trying to upload images it have read-write permissions

Comment: how can i know? do i need to go to the server and set the permission? before i was using cpanel, now i transfered to godaddy. or do i need to use any code?

Comment: please help me further. can you also check my code. i'm desperate about this thing. please please help me

Comment: If you have ftp details then goto directory , right click & set permission 777

Comment: i have set it already.

Comment: @Rohit i ahve it set to 777 but still not uploading the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the major two change in your code :

1. Replace code  if(isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
   With  if($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']!=""){
2. Remove path from default image : $uploadFilename = 'def_img.jpg';

I have tried its working fine. The complete code by which i have test that default image and uploaded image both available for further processing.

```
$directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

// make a note of the directory that will recieve the uploaded files //i made it as the same directory where the .php file is
$uploadsDirectory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory_self;
#echo "$uploadsDirectory<br>";

#exit;
$fieldname = 'file';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{           
    if($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']!="")
    {
        $allowedExts = array("jpeg", "jpg");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);
        $extension = end($temp);

        $notallowedExts = array("png", "gif", "pdf", "doc", "docx", "txt", "html", "xlsx", "mov");
        $nottemp = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);
        $notextension = end($nottemp);

        if ((($_FILES['file']['type'] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES['file']['type'] == "image/jpg")) && ($_FILES['file']['size'] < 1300000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))  
        {       

          $now = time();
          while(file_exists($uploadFilename = $uploadsDirectory.$now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]['name']))
          {
              $now++;
          }
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'], $uploadFilename);
        }
        elseif(($_FILES['file']['size'] > 1300000)||(in_array($notextension, $notallowedExts)))
        {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
            echo 'alert("Invalid file upload. Please check your input.");'; 
            echo 'window.location.href = "index.php";';
            echo '</script>';
            die();
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        $uploadFilename = "images.jpg";
    }   
}

/*$get_title = $_POST['title'];
$story = "My super story begins with " . $_POST['story'] . " My task was " . $_POST['task'] ." With the super power of ". $_POST['power'] ." I solved it by ". $_POST['solve'] ." The result was ". $_POST['result'];

if (!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($office_id) && !empty($title) && !empty($var_title) && !empty($var_story) && !empty($var_task) && !empty($var_power) && !empty($var_solve) && !empty($var_result)) {

*/
echo " FILE : $uploadFilename";
//header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$upload = $uploadFilename;
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg("bg.jpg");
$img2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($upload);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$font = 'arialbi.ttf';
$font2 = 'ariali.ttf';

$newtitle = wordwrap($title, 24, "\n", true);
$newertitle = explode("\n", $newtitle);


imagettftext($im, 33, 0, 8, 270, $black, $font, $newertitle[0]);
imagettftext($im, 33, 0, 8, 320, $black, $font, $newertitle[1]);
imagettftext($im, 12, 0, 283, 365, $black, $font, $namehere);

$newtext = wordwrap($story, 50, "\n", true);
$newertext = explode("\n", $newtext);
imagettftext($im, 10, 0, 283, 385, $black, $font2, $newertext[0]);
imagettftext($im, 10, 0, 283, 400, $black, $font2, $newertext[1]);

imagecopyresampled($im, $img2, 10, 350, 0, 0, 263, 175, imagesx($img2), imagesy($img2));

$date_created = date("YmdHis");//get date created
$img_name = "-img_entry.jpg"; //the file name of the generated image
$img_newname = $date_created . $img_name; //datecreated+name
$img_dir =dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) ."/". $img_newname; //the location to save the image 
imagejpeg($im, $img_dir , 80); //function to save the image with the name and quality

$newpath = "/home/content/52/12096052/html/Testupdate/image_entry/";
$newdir = $newpath.$img_newname;
copy ($img_dir, $newdir); //copy to new folder


$http_dir = 'https://www.uaewebdeveloper.com/Testupdate/image_entry/';
$post_link = $http_dir . $img_newname;

$msg = 'Super Story by ';
$post_msg = $msg.$name;

imagedestroy($im);
//}
```

Comment: thank you for answering. i will try it now. ill let u know immediatiely. pls hold on

Comment: hi i'm still getting the same error. what am i doing wrong here? please help me further

Comment: I hv test as per your query for further assistance you have to provide the full code.

Comment: Hi I reaaly appreciate your help. thank you. i edited my question. my full code for processor.php is there.

Comment: i tried your code. but i cant see the image being uploded in  my directory.

Comment: are you still there? plaese help me

Comment: Ya i got the Image in the same directory but it generate only bg.jpg file.

Comment: hi! i solved it! yey :) and your answer helped me. im going to mark your answer now:) again, thank you very much! :)

Comment: hi i thought i solved it. only to find ouy that im still getting the same error on ie8. any idea? hope you can help me further. thanks